# "You have to specify either input_ids or inputs_embeds", but I did specify the input_ids

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I trained a BERT based encoder decoder model (`EncoderDecoderModel`) named `ed_model` with HuggingFace's transformers module.

I used the `BertTokenizer` named as `input_tokenizer`

I tokenized the input with:

```
txt = "Some wonderful sentence to encode"
inputs = input_tokenizer(txt, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
print(inputs)
```

The output clearly shows that a `input_ids` is the return dict

```
{'input_ids': tensor([[ 101, 5660, 7975, 2127, 2053, 2936, 5061,  102]], device='cuda:0'), 'token_type_ids': tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], device='cuda:0'), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], device='cuda:0')}
```

But when I try to predict, I get this error:
`ed_model.forward(**inputs)`

> ValueError: You have to specify either input_ids or inputs_embeds

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please post (always) the full error stacktrace and shows us how initialized the `ed_model` (before your training).

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue, see: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3626

Answer (score 9):

Well, apparently this is a known issue, for example: [This issue of T5](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3626)

The problem is that there's probably a renaming procedure in the code, since we use a encoder-decoder architecture we have 2 types of input ids.

The solution is to explicitly specify the type of input id

```
ed_model.forward(decoder_input_ids=inputs['input_ids'],**inputs)
```

I wish it was documented somewhere, but now you know :-)